# Failed to load task class org.apache.synapse.startup.Task in adding a new "scheduled task"

Tags: wso2, scheduled-tasks, wso2-esb

I am in the process of add a new scheduled task. in the UI, i have to put the "Task Implementation". 
As mentioned in the WSO2 documentation I implemented my java class by org.apache.synapse.task.Task. So I put "org.apache.synapse.task.Task" in the UI as the "Task Implementation". But when i click shedule it says "Failed to load task class org.apache.synapse.startup.Task". I also tried with "org.apache.synapse.startup.Task". But both classes failed to load.

Can any one please help me to sorted this out?

I am using Enterprise Service Bus 4.8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks

Task Implementation - The implementation class of the task. To use the default task implementation that is available with the ESB (and therefore can be used without downloading any third-party libraries or custom JARs), specify  ***org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector***. This class simply injects a specified message into the Synapse environment at ESB startup

If you write a custom task, you must specify YOUR implementation, but not 'org.apache.synapse.task.Task'